# java implement generic interface in an anonymous class

Tags: java, generics

Given the following interface,

```
 public interface Callback<T> {
    <K, V> T execute(Operation<K, V> operation) throws SomeException;
 }
```

How would I implement the interface in a new anonymous class where `operation` is of type `Operation<String,String>`

e.g, this doesn't compile:

```
 Callback<Boolean> callback = new Callback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean execute(Operation<String, String> operation) {
              return true;
        }
 };
 executor.execute(callback);
```

Comment: What compilation error do you get? I can see that your function does not have a return statement, which is a compilation error.

Comment: what is the reason of compilation error? And where is `SomeException`?

Comment: I suggest you you not re-use the name of any common class or interface and use a different name instead. Re-using names leads to confusion like you have.

Comment: A good IDE should generate the correct way to implement this.

Comment: Note, the interface method could more easily be written `T execute(Operation<?, ?> operation) throws SomeException;`.

Comment: * edited to add return statement. compilation error is CallbackCaller is not abstract and does not override abstract method <K,V>execute(Operation<K, V> operation)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the generics on the method are unrelated to the class generic parameters

you need to repeat them on the method for it to be correct, e.g.

```
Callback<Boolean> callback = new Callback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public <X,Y> Boolean execute(Operation<X, Y> operation) {

        }
};
executor.execute(callback);
```

In other words the interface requires an execute method that works on any Operation parameters.

If you want a callback that only works on specific parameters you need to make them part of the class signature, e.g.

```
 public interface Callback<T,K,V> {
    T execute(Operation<K, V> operation) throws SomeException;
 }
```

that would then let you do

```
Callback<Boolean,String,String> callback = new Callback<Boolean,String,String>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean execute(Operation<String, String> operation) {

        }
};
executor.execute(callback);
```

I cannot see a route to getting what you want... unless you start using the `<? super K,? super V>` or `<? extends K,? extends V>` forms which may restrict you too much.

Here is what your interface erases to

```
 public interface Callback<T> {
    T execute(Operation<Object, Object> operation) throws SomeException;
 }
```

then when you instantiate with `T == Boolean` we get

```
 public interface Callback {
    Boolean execute(Operation<Object, Object> operation) throws SomeException;
 }
```

which cannot be implemented by a

```
    Boolean execute(Operation<String, String> operation) throws SomeException;
```

method as the in parameters are narrower. You can widen in parameters and narrow out parameters but you cannot go the other way.

That explains why you can change the return type (out parameter) from `Object` to `Boolean` as anyone expecting an `Object` will be happy with a `Boolean`.

Conversely we cannot widen the return type as that would give a `ClassCastException` to anyone calling the method and acting on the result.

The method arguments (in parameters) can only be widened. Now it is somewhat complex for method arguments as Java sees different types as different methods, so you can legally have

```
public interface Callback<T> {
  T execute(Object key, Object value);
}

Callback<Boolean> cb = new Callback<Boolean> {
  @Override
  public Boolean execute(Object k, Object v) { ... }
  // not an @Override
  public Boolean execute(String k, String v) { ... }
}
```

because the second method has a different signature. But your `Operation<X,Y>` class gets erased to just the raw type irrespective of whether it is an `Operation<String,String>` or `Operation<X,Y>`

There is one thing you could do... but it gets messy!

```
public interface StringOperation extends Operation<String,String> {}
```

then you can do

```
Callback<Boolean> cb = new Callback<Boolean> {
  @Override
  public <K,V> Boolean execute(Operation<K,V> o) { ... }
  // not an @Override
  public Boolean execute(StringOperation o) { ... }
}
```

but keep in mind that the `execute(Callback<?>)` method will be calling `<K,V> Boolean execute(Operation<K,V> o)` and not `Boolean execute(StringOperation o)`

Answer (score 5):

Because the type parameter in your class name and the type parameter in the method are actually different You can do below.

```
   @Override
    public <K, V> Boolean execute(Operation<K, V> operation)
            throws SomeException {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: this works, but what if I explicitly want operation to use generic types <String,String> in side execute method?

Comment: You will have to change `Callback<T>` to `Callback<T,K,V>`

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately in this case, this was not an interface I control.

Comment: @user1735096 Then you should do this.